# android close managed cursor

Tags: android, crash, cursor

I have a code which takes images from gallery using gallery intent and data is send to my activity as an uri like:

> content://media/external/images/media/338

I need to get the path of this picture and I am using

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, projection, null, null, null);
    try {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(0);
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

but this code causes a crash on android ICS when trying to close a managed cursor. This is a known issue ([see issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23746)). Is there a way to close this cursor without causing a crash? I don't want to exit this method without closing the cursor. I need to suport android 2.1 and up. Thanks

Comment: you are not supposed to close a managedQuery

Comment: I know now, but it sucks that it's working on android 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 and it's crashes on android 4.0

Comment: don't use a managedQuery, then

Answer (score 0):

found it:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null);
    try {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(0);
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```